# Reference to the cell which contains a certain date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a problem with the query function in Google Sheets.

```
=QUERY(A1:D7; "Select B where C contains '"& F1 &"' ";0)
```

These formula works if the cell F1 contains a text or a number. But if it contains a date it turns with a N/A mistake.

[image: table in question]

As a result I need to get the data from the column B which is placed in the line with the certain date.

Please, could you help me? What do I do wrong?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 1):

for a date do:

```
=QUERY(A1:D7; "select B where A = date '"&TEXT(F1; "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"; 0)
```

or do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT(A1:D7); "select Col2 where Col1 = '"&F1&"'"; 0))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for both formulas!!